# Does the from address have to exist when sending an email

Tags: email

Does the from address have to exist when sending an email?

Having issues with people receiving my emails when sending from code, and the only thing I can think of that is different is that the from email address does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't, there's lots of reasons why the main may not get delivered. Jeff Attwood has a good article that spells out a lot of the things to look at [sending mail through code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html).

Answer (score 2):

The from address doesn't have to exist but note that if the sender's domain doesn't exist the message is far more likely to be flagged as spam.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to exist but doesn't have to be accurate.

Comment: Huh? How can it exist and not be accurate? There's no fuzzy logic in email delivery. It either exists or it doesn't.